# Display date selected in one form to another form

Tags: c#

I want to display the date which is selected in another form using monthCalender control..
Here is my code..

```
private void monthCalendar1_DateSelected(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
    {            
        ActivityScheduler frm1 = new ActivityScheduler();
        frm1.Show();
    } 

private void ActivityScheduler_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open) { con.Close(); }
        con.Open();
        RemainderPopUp frm = new RemainderPopUp();
        string s = "select * from [Activity_Scheduler]";
        SqlCommand sCmd = new SqlCommand(s, con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sCmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        da.Fill(ds, "[Activity_Scheduler]");
        datagridActivityScheduler.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

        datagridActivityScheduler.AllowUserToAddRows = true;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = ds.Tables["Activity_Scheduler"];
        if (dt == null)
        {

            datagridActivityScheduler.Rows[0].Cells[3].Value = frm.monthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.ToShortDateString();
            MessageBox.Show(datagridActivityScheduler.Rows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString());

        }
        con.Close();
    }
```

It is displaying the correct value in messagebox..but the value is not displaying in datagridview...
Plz anybody help me out..

Comment: `frm` is a new RemainderPopup form, you need the existing instance, there are lots of examples of this here on SO

Answer (score 0):

Try Following Code :

```
 form_load()
 {
 private string myDate="1999/12/12";

    // Declare a Date property of type string:
    public string Name
    {
        get 
        {
           return myDate; 
        }
        set 
        {
           myName = value; 
        }
 }

private void monthCalendar1_DateSelected(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
{            
    ActivityScheduler frm1 = new ActivityScheduler();
    ActivityScheduler.myDate = frm.monthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.ToShortDateString()
    frm1.Show();
}
```

Now you can get date on other form as :

string myDate = frm1.myDate();

Let me know if any queries.

Comment: IF you simply want to pass data from one form to another form you can have simple solution and it is to create a property assign a value to it and you can access it on another form.

Comment: You can set datatable content on form load event , You can observer my edit for set and get property of form.